# C# WPF Grid/GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

What I want to have:

- a Grid-Splitter with 3 Columns
- the MinWidth for all 3 Columns should work
- the left and the right column should have a "defaultSize" like 100 and 200
- when I resize the Form, only the column in the middle should resize. the columns on the left and on the right should stay the same size
- if I add controls to the form, i want them to change their size according to the splitter

What I have:

- I have a Grid with 3 Columns
- the MinWidth for all 3 Columns works, but only with the ColumnWidth="*"
- I dont know how to set a "DefaultSize" for the left and right column, because if I change the ColumnWidth, the MinWidth doesnt work anymore
- when I resize the form, all 3 Columns change their size, not only the column in the middle

  ```
  <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsLocked="True" Background="Pink">
      <ToolBar Height="26" Background="Beige">
      </ToolBar>
  </ToolBarTray>

  <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="23" Background="Orange"/>

  <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="50"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width ="*" MinWidth="100"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="50"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" ShowsPreview="True" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>


      <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Width="5" ShowsPreview="True" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

  </Grid>
  ```

Thanks so far :)

Comment: How about setting the Width to "Auto" for your other columns as well? That way your columns will have MinWidth as their default width. If you want to do more logic around your widhts you need to do it in code behind or bind to some other element's width

Comment: Okay, so with the Width=Auto for the left and the right column, the MinWidth of the column in the middle doesnt work anymore - so you think i have to solve this in code? ..... I also dont know how to set a "Default" size for the left and right column since it is "Auto"

Answer (score 2):

set the width (default size) for left and right column and it should be work

```
<Grid>
  <StatusBar Height="23" Background="Orange" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
  <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50" Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50" Width="200"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <GridSplitter
        Width="5"
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="Red"
        ShowsPreview="True"/>
     <GridSplitter
        Width="5"
        Grid.Column="3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="Red"
        ShowsPreview="True"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT**

here is a fix for the first grid maxwidth problem

```
<Grid x:Name="Root">
      <Grid.Resources>
        <local:MaxWidthConverter x:Key="MaxWidthConverter" />
      </Grid.Resources>

      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50"
                            Width="200"
                            MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MaxWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=260}" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200"
                            Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50"
                            Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Width="5"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Red"
                      ShowsPreview="True" />
        <GridSplitter Width="5"
                      Grid.Column="3"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Red"
                      ShowsPreview="True" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

simple converter to calculate the maxwidth for the first column (260 = 200 minwidth + 50 minwidth + 5 splitter width + 5 splitter width

```
public class MaxWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    double minWidth;
    if (value is double && parameter is string && double.TryParse((string)parameter, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out minWidth)) {
      var maxWidth = (double)value - minWidth;
      return maxWidth < 0 ? 0 : maxWidth;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! but can you explain me, how to fix the minWidth for the column in the middle?

Comment: Thank you very much so far!!! But that's strange. For the left and the right column, the MinWidth and the MaxWidth work properly (also without your converter). But for the Column in the middle, neither MinWidth nor MaxWidth work....